# XMLWriter extends attribute name with zdef?

Tags: java, xml-serialization, jackson, xmlmapper, fasterxml

I try to serialize some config classes to xml config files using the XMLMapper.
but I have some trouble with the attribute generation. Actually the generated XML is perfect, but  XMLMapper adds sometimes a prefix to my attribute names.

e.g.

```
<Config zdef-2031720317:value="0">
```

instead of

```
<Config value="0">
```

This is really bad because i can't process the xml Structure afterwards with XOM anymore :(

Where is this effect coming from? 
I found already the fact that the xml generator seems to auto fix the namespace to make the attributes unique. Why is this necessary and how can i avoid it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing that has often caused problems with `XmlMapper` is underlying XML Stax library -- one included in JDK sometimes adds unnecessary namespace prefixes.
The solution is to use [Woodstox](http://woodstox.codehaus.org) Stax implementation instead, as it is known to work better in general, and also in this specific case.

If you use Maven, you can just add this in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
  <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

and your problem may be solved. As an added bonus, this is faster XML parser as well.

Answer (score 8):

For those who are looking for a non woodstox answer. This did the trick for me:

```
xmlMapper.getFactory().getXMLOutputFactory().setProperty("javax.xml.stream.isRepairingNamespaces", false);
```